# How to install Lua DBI on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, lua

I'm taking the advice of this page for Mac to compile Lua-DBI from source:

http://prosody.im/doc/depends#luadbi

But I don't know how to compile it from source. I get the following error.

```
make psql
gcc -c -o build/dbd_postgresql_main.o dbd/postgresql/main.c -g -pedantic -Wall -O2 -shared -fpic -I /usr/include/lua5.1 -I /usr/include/mysql -I /usr/include/postgresql/ -I /opt/ibm/db2exc/V9.5/include/ -I /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client/rdbms/public/ -I .
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-shared'
In file included from dbd/postgresql/main.c:1:
dbd/postgresql/dbd_postgresql.h:1:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm a noob. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get LuaDBI without having to build it from the source on Mac OS X with [LuaRocks](http://luarocks.org/modules/luarocks/luadbi): `luarocks install luadbi-mysql` (for MYSQL) and `luarocks install luasql-postgres` (for Postgres).

Luarocks itself can be installed on Mac using [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh) as follows:

```
brew update
brew install luarocks
```

For more information see [the LuaRocks github repo](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Mac-OS-X).